# Reloading UITableView resets view's subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my view controller has a UITableView and my app is a chatting app where the table loads new chats. so i added a textfield that when pressed it goes over the keyboard so the user can see it. now when the textfield has been moved upwards and a new chat is available and the table view reloads, the textfield drops down to it's original place in which it was positioned and the keyboard is still in it's place as the textfield didn't resign it. How can i prevent the subviews of my view to reset to their original settings when i reload the table view?

Edit: the textfield isn't added to a cell. The view has a UITableView that i resized to keep space for the textfield in the bottom.

Comment: isn't it possible the cell with the textfield gets queued, that's why it's not resigning?

Comment: oh now the textfield isn't added to a cell. the view has a UITableView that i resized to keep space for the textfield in the bottom.

Comment: +1 I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have done it already I suggest to have a regular view with a regular UIViewController as "host". Within that you have the textfiled and what ever else may be needed. And you have a container view where the Table View should reside. Within that container you nest your UITableView and its controler. By doing so reloading and other table manipulation tasks (like adding or deleting cells ect) cannot influence the layout of the hosting view.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is a chatting app, I suppose you have your answering field at the end of your UITableView.

So just add a footer to it, containing your field.
Resizing the footer shouldn't mess up your all cells.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = ...
```

Then you don't need to resize your table since the field is part of it (it's in the scrollview of your tableview)